# Webpack libraryTarget: "module" generates code with `'return' outside of function`

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I'm trying to output an ESM module with WebPack 5.  My understanding is that this feature has been added in version 5, and is used by specifying `{output: libraryTarget: 'module'}}` and `{experiments: {outputModule: true}}`.

I believe that what I'm seeing is just a WebPack bug - perhaps related to `outputModule` still being experimental, but I'm not very well versed in WebPack so could easily have missed something.

I get an error `'return' outside of function`.  With the configuration below, this happens when I run `npx webpack`.  If I change `mode` to `'development'`, then it generates a bundle which indeed has a `return` statement at the end such that attempting to use it generates a similar error at runtime.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
    //using 'production' rather than 'development' catches error earlier.
    mode: 'production',
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'hello.js',
        libraryTarget: "module",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
export default function() { return 42; }
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "webpackTest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "webpack": "webpack",
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
      "webpack": "^5.5.1",
      "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Not yet supported at the moment https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933#issuecomment-715903657

Comment: @chenxsan thanks. I must say, the documentation could be clearer on the subject.  I was a bit thrown by https://github.com/purtuga/esm-webpack-plugin 'IMPORTANT : Webpack 5 has been released and with it comes support for output ES Modules. See documentation here. There is currently no plan to udpate this plugin to support Webpack 5 and those looking to upgrade should instead migrate to use the new features of Webpack 5.' (not that webpack themselves are responsible for what third party plugin authors write).

Comment: You can help improve the documentation :)

Comment: Fair point :)  I'm not necessarily averse to contributing; maybe for now I'm going to file a bug on esm-webpack-plugin as that seems to be the thing that most threw me.  I think the issue you linked to did come up in a search but I saw it was from 2016 and assumed no longer relevant.